# Java ServerApplicationConfig

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, java-websocket

I'm trying to configure a server endpoint and I don't understand 1 thing. Does the endpoint get automatically added in the `endpointClasses` set? Then all I have to do is iterate throught that set and if it matches `ServerEndPoint.class` then I create a `ServerEndpointConfig` for it?

```
@Override
public Set<ServerEndpointConfig> getEndpointConfigs(Set<Class<? extends Endpoint>> endpointClasses) {

});
```

The endpoint:

```
public class ServerEndPoint extends Endpoint{
  ...
}
```